# TreeView with Columns slow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, virtualization

I want to display a large hierarchical structure split in columns in my WPF application. My intention was to use a TreeView with columns to achieve that.

With small amounts of data the control works fine. Scrolling is smooth and the loading time is also acceptable (<1s). But with large amount of data scrolling starts to hang and is not smooth anymore and loading needs several seconds.

Here the code of the data structure:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}


public class Contact:Person
{

    public bool Test { get; set; }
}
```

Here the code of the used converter:

```
public class LevelToIndentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly LevelToIndentConverter DefaultInstance = new LevelToIndentConverter();

    public static LevelToIndentConverter Default
    {
        get { return DefaultInstance; }
    }

    private const double IndentSize = 20.0;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness((int)value * IndentSize, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

TreeListView code:

```
public class TreeListView : TreeView
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), typeof(TreeListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new GridViewColumnCollection(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

    public GridViewColumnCollection Columns
    {
        get { return (GridViewColumnCollection)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new TreeListViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is TreeListViewItem;
    }

    public TreeListView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TreeListView);
        Columns = new GridViewColumnCollection();
    }
}

public class TreeListViewItem : TreeViewItem
{

    private int level = -1;

    public int Level
    {
        get
        {
            if (level != -1) { return level; }

            var parent = ItemsControlFromItemContainer(this) as TreeListViewItem;
            level = (parent != null) ? parent.Level + 1 : 0;
            return level;
        }
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new TreeListViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is TreeListViewItem;
    }

    public TreeListViewItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TreeListViewItem);
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButton.TreeExpander" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Level, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}}, Converter={x:Static controls:LevelToIndentConverter.Default}}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType= {x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid x:Name="ArrowGrid" Grid.Column="0" Width="20">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Up_Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False">
                                    <TextBlock Text="-"/>
                                </ContentControl>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="Down_Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" Focusable="False">
                                    <TextBlock Text="+"></TextBlock>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Grid>

                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasItems,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="ArrowGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Down_Arrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Up_Arrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TreeListViewScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" Focusable="false"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

                                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>

                            <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                                CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                                CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                                CanVerticallyScroll="False" />
                        </DockPanel>


                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TreeListView.Base" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListView}" >
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit" Value="Item" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource TreeListViewScrollViewerStyle}">
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="TreeListViewItem.Base" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}" >
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}">
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                        <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Columns="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:TreeListView}}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" />
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="HasHeader" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Header" Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeListView.Base}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListView}" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeListViewItem.Base}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <controls:TreeListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" />
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        <controls:TreeListView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="100">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Resources>

                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Person}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Contact}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataTemplate.Resources>

                        <ToggleButton Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButton.TreeExpander}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="300">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Person}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Contact}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataTemplate.Resources>

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </controls:TreeListView.Columns>
    </controls:TreeListView>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var persons = new List<Person>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                FirstName = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Hans", i),
                LastName = "Wurst",
                Contacts = new List<Contact>()
            };

            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                person.Contacts.Add(new Contact { FirstName = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Contact", j), LastName = "-" });
            }

            persons.Add(person);    
        }

        this.DataContext = persons;
    }
}
```

Does anybody has an idea why this view is lagging? I tried to enable virtualization to improve performance but it doesn't solve the problem.

What I found out so far is that it seems to have something to do with the `GridViewRowPresenter`. When I remove it everything works fine.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you very much,
Stefan

### Update

Virtualization is activated for the `TreeListView`. See style I `TreeListView.Base`. The style is applied on the `TreeListView` by line

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeListView.Base}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListView}" />
```

. Virtualization works as far as I can check this with WPF snoop.

### Update 2

I have create a sample application on GitHub with the here posted code. You can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/sla89/TreeListView/tree/master)

It also contains an implementation of the `TreeListView` styled without the GridRows to illustrate that even with all childs loaded everything works fine and smooth.

Comment: Have you tried use the attached property `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing`? And  set `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode`  to `Recycling`.

Comment: I have done this in my Style _TreeListView.Base_ already and the style is applied on the TreeListView by line _    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeListView.Base}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListView}" />_. Virtualization works as far as I can check this with WPF snoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` and `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing`can significantly reduce the memory consumption and intensely improve performance. Please, see the following code snippet:

```
<TreeView x:Name=”myTreeView”

      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"

      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

**Update:**

Maybe it helps, but try to set properties not in the `Style`, but in your custom control `TreeListView`:

```
<controls:TreeListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"   >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" />
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </controls:TreeListView>
```

Try to load data when the user expands the TreeView. Normally, a user will not require 50,000 nodes to be open on their screen at once. Only load the children that the user needs to see, along with whatever child information you need to properly display.

**Update 1:**

It looks like `GridViewRowPresenter`is the cause of your performance question. I've used `ContentPresenter` and performance become like in your `FastTreeView`, but `Header`s are not correct to their columns. You should correct it

```
<Style x:Key="TreeListViewItem.Base" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListViewItem}" >
...
<VirtualizingStackPanel>
   <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">                                  
       <!--<GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Columns="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:TreeListView}}" />-->
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1">
          <ContentPresenter.Resources>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Person}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                 </StackPanel>                                            
             </DataTemplate>

             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Contact}">
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
              </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
         </ContentPresenter>                               
        </Border>
       <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" />
    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
```

Comment: I have done this in my Style _TreeListView.Base_ already and the style is applied on the TreeListView by line _    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeListView.Base}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:TreeListView}" />_. Virtualization works as far as I can check this with WPF snoop.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and have moved the `VirtualizingStackPanel` stuff in my control without success. Actually it seems not to be related with the loaded childs. When I remove them (even the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`) it still is slow and scrolling is not smooth. Please see my first post - I have provided the source code on GitHub.

Comment: @Skully the link is broken

Comment: I could fix the problem by setting the `Height` property of `GridRowPresenter` in style `TreeListViewItem.Base`. This solves the performance issues. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue.

It seems that the root cause of the performance problems was that `GridViewRowPresenter` has not set a fix height.

When I set a height on the `GridViewRowPresenter` in the `TreeListViewItem.Base`style everything works like a charm:

```
<GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Height="20" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Columns="{Binding Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:TreeListView}}" />
```

Thank you for your help.